# Nuxt 2 layout/error.vue template is only rendered in development mode

Tags: nuxt.js

When my API throws a server error (500), i am redirected to my layout/error.vue template in my development environment, but not in production, where the API call seems to be failing 'silently' in the background.

I have gathered so far that i need to explicitly throw an error in the catch clause of my API calling methods in order to trigger the error.vue layout being invoked, but why is this not necessary to do in development?
If i receive a 404 in the client (by, for instance, trying to access an invalid route in my app) it works fine in both environments - my error.vue layout is rendered.

My app is SSR, and i have been using this resource to implement an error page:
https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/concepts/views/#error-page